# Error with uploading video from using PHP

Tags: php, xcode, server

I am trying to upload video using PHP from my app which build on Xcode, the code is working perfect with size below 10MB, but if the video is bigger I have response from the PHP (There was an error uploading the file, please try again!).

Her is the what I am using in Xcode:

```
- (IBAction)postVideoAction:(id)sender {
if(_postImageView.image == nil)
{
[UIUtils messageAlert:@"Please chose a video" title:@"Ok" delegate:nil];
return;
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){


NSData* videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[_videoUrl path]];
long videoSize = [videoData length]/4069/4069;
if(videoSize <= 40) // check size of video
{

NSString *filenames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TextLabel"];      //set name here
NSLog(@"%@", filenames);
NSString *urlString = @"http://MyWebSite/sendImages.php";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filenames\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[filenames dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *uname = @"TheUserName";
NSString *datestring = @"Photo";
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@user%@.mov\"\r\n", uname,datestring]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
NSLog(@"finish");

     }


else {


[UIUtils messageAlert:nil title:@"Video must be less than 160 MB" delegate:self];

if (_conn == nil)
_conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
_ReleaseObj(request);
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

});
});

}
```

And her is the PHP file:

```
<? 
$myparam = $_FILES['userfile']; 
$target_path = "theUserPhoto/";
if(move_uploaded_file($myparam['tmp_name'], $target_path . basename( $myparam['name'])))

{ echo "The file ". basename( $myparam['name']). " has been uploaded"; } 

else 

{ echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; } 

?>
```

As I said the code is working perfect but with video size less than 10MB.

Can anyone help me to find the answer?

Thanks

Comment: The `upload_max_filesize` directive is set to 10Mb. To upload something larger you need to increase that value in PHP.INI. The PHP reference is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize). This may have been set by your ISP and there may be nothing you can do, except move to another ISP.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I am not good enough in PHP. Do you know where to add the upload_max_filesize in my above PHP code

Comment: You don't. You set it in php.ini. See my previous comment.